# Transfer data between tables in Amazon Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, amazon-data-pipeline

How to process and update/append data from table1 to table2 in AWS Redshift?

The transfer of data between the tables needs to happen automatically whenever the data is loaded from S3 into table1.

Table1 data is copied from AWS S3 though AWS Data Pipeline.

Comment: you could use a view?

Answer (score 0):

You can run an SQL command to copy the data, such as:

```
INSERT INTO table2
SELECT * FROM table1
```

However, there is no mechanism to trigger this automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the response. If I have to automate the whole process, as in load the data in to table2 as soon as table1 is updated from the s3 through data pipeline, I need to unload to s3 and load it again to table2 through pipeline?

Comment: It would probably be easier to have Pipeline trigger some script that runs an SQL command in your Redshift cluster -- much simpler than doing an export/import, but it will require you to write the script. For example, use `psql` or a Python library that connects to PostgreSQL, but point it at the Redshift cluster.